# Conversion from string to date failed in stored procedure to fill calender

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is my stored procedure I am trying to use to fill a table in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [IMM1069].[uspVulKalender]
   @jaarVanaf varchar(10),
   @jaarTot varchar(10)
AS
   declare @startdag varchar(20)
   declare @einddag varchar(20)
   declare @lopendeDag date = null
   declare @weekdag bit = 0

   set @startdag = '01/01/'+@jaarVanaf
   set @einddag = '31/12/'+@jaarTot

BEGIN

   set @lopendeDag = cast(@startdag as date)

   While @lopendeDag <= cast(@einddag as date)
     if datepart(dw,getdate()) = 6 or datepart(dw,getdate()) = 7
        set @weekdag = 0
     else
        set @weekdag = 1

     print(@lopendeDag)

     insert into [IMM1069].[tbl_kalender](tbl_kalender.datum, tbl_kalender.dag, tbl_kalender.dag_naam, tbl_kalender.isWeekdag, tbl_kalender.week, tbl_kalender.maand, tbl_kalender.maand_naam, tbl_kalender.jaar)
     values(
       @lopendeDag,               --datum
       datepart(dw,@lopendeDag),  -- weekdaynr
       datename(dw,@lopendeDag),  -- name day
       @weekdag,              -- isWeekday
       datepart(wk,@lopendeDag),  -- weeknr
       datepart(mm,@lopendeDag),  -- monthnr
       datename(mm,@lopendeDag),  -- monthname
       datepart(yyyy,@lopendeDag)
      )

     set @lopendeDag = dateadd(dd,1,@lopendeDag)
END
```

I get the following error when executing the stored procedure:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspVulKalender, Line 21
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jannick

Comment: What values do you supply when you call the proc?

Comment: [Why are you using ambiguous, regional formats like `dd/mm/yyyy`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx)? Why is year a `VARCHAR(10)`? Do you know of any years that are something other than four characters? [Why are you using lazy shorthand like `mm`? Why not type out `MONTH`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)?

Comment: (Also, your WHILE loop is infinite, and I don't think you meant to insert Thursday, etc. on every single row - your code should use the variables, not GETDATE()...)

Comment: @jpw; I supply 2 years when executing the stored procedure (for example 2014 as startyear and 2015 as end year). So the procedure should start as of 01/01/2014 until 31/12/2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much more efficient way to do this. Whenever you think you're going to get a bunch of rows and loop through them one at a time, try to think about it differently. SQL Server is optimized to work in sets, not in loops. Here is a set-based alternative:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [IMM1069].[uspVulKalender]
  @jaarVanaf INT,
  @jaarTot   INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; 

  IF @jaarVanaf NOT BETWEEN 2010 AND 2030
    OR @jaarTot NOT BETWEEN 2010 AND 2030
  BEGIN
    RETURN;
  END

  ;WITH n(n) AS
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_columns
  ), d(d) AS
  (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @jaarVanaf-1900, 0)) FROM n 
      WHERE n <= DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(YEAR, @jaarVanaf-1900, 0), 
      DATEADD(YEAR, @jaarTot-1899, 0))
  )
  --insert into [IMM1069].[tbl_kalender]
  --(datum,dag,dag_naam,isWeekdag,week,maand,maand_naam,jaar)
  SELECT 
    d, 
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d),  -- datum
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d),  -- weekdaynr
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) IN (6,7) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,  -- isWeekday
    DATEPART(WEEK, d),     -- weeknr
    DATEPART(MONTH, d),    -- monthnr
    DATENAME(MONTH, d),    -- monthname
    DATEPART(YEAR, d)      -- yearnr
  FROM d;
END
```

Some notes:

- Pass integers for the years. There is no good reason to pass a string here, and then use concatenation to form regional, ambiguous date strings.
- The `sys.all_columns` query should support ~8,400 rows in an empty database, depending on version of SQL Server. This will let you build a date range spanning about 23 years. If you need more, you could cross join to `sys.objects` or you could create your own numbers table.
- The `insert` does not need a table prefix on every column. I've commented out the `insert` above so you can test the output before trying to perform the insert.
- I've spelled out the dateparts instead of using abbreviations, as these can cause confusion. For example, try `SELECT DATEPART(Y, GETDATE()), DATEPART(W, GETDATE());` - does that yield what you expect?
- Some blog posts for background:

  - https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries
  - https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations
  - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1
  - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2
  - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this as SQL Server 2012 so you should use the wonderful new *FromParts* method. If it's a date or time like item, there's a corresponding *FromParts* method. In your case, you're looking at a `DateFromParts`.

I think Aaraon's already pointed out that you shouldn't be using string to store dates. Nasty business and given your non-English source code, I would think Internationalization wouldn't be as foreign a concept as it is to other (and now I step down from my soapbox)

You still have a logic issue but the fix I would make would be to

1. change the data type to `date` for @startdag and @einddag.
2. instead of string concatenation, use the [DateFromParts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx).
3. Your While loop comparison is simplified to `@lopendeDag <= @einddag`

Affected code

```
   declare @startdag date
   declare @einddag date
   declare @lopendeDag date = null
   declare @weekdag bit = 0

   set @startdag = DATEFROMPARTS(@jaarVanaf, 1, 1) 

   set @einddag = DATEFROMPARTS(@jaarTot, 12, 31)
   set @lopendeDag = cast(@startdag as date)

   While @lopendeDag <= @einddag
```

Comment: Hey Billinkc, I'm using the express version of SQL Server 2012. Apparently the DATEFROMPARTS-function isn't build-in in this version because I get following error when executing the stored procedure: "datefromparts is not a recognized function name". But Aaron already fixed the problem. Thanks for your effort though! Gr Jannick

Comment: @GrJannick are you sure you are using SQL Server 2012? What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` say? I bet you are using 2012 SSMS but connecting to an older engine.